# is it possible to pass text in batch file to another batch file that is password protected

Tags: command-line, batch, passwords, batch-file

so heres my thing. I've created a password generator in a batch file and I'm passing the generated password to another batch file to save it.
My question is can I password protect the password storage file and still be able to write to it using the other batch file ?

Comment: How do you want to protect the file? Normally you **call** another batch passing arguments and share variables in the same environment. Once a file is protected (however you do it) you can't simply append to it.

Comment: Are you trying to solve a bigger issue? Security related coding is not trivial and there might be an easier way to solve your overall goal.

Comment: Hi ..more a case of wanting to be able to have a txt file that has a password that thee password generater can pass that created password to. Not sure if its possible or not. At the moment my txt file is not locked. But if possible i would like to have it protected. or if you guys have a better idea im all ears